# Trying to Understand NSString::initWithBytes

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm attempting conversion of a legacy C++ program to objective-C.  The program needs an array of the 256 possible ASCII characters (8-bits per character).  I'm attempting to use the `NSString` method `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` to do so.  Unfortunately, when coded as shown below, it crashes (although it compiles).

```
NSString*     charasstring[256];
unsigned char char00;
int           temp00;
    for (temp00 = 0; temp00 <= 255; ++temp00)
        {
        char00 = (unsigned char)temp00;
        [charasstring[temp00] initWithBytes:&char00 length:1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
        }
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

First, the method is simply `initWithBytes:length:encoding` and not the `NSString::initWithBytes` you used in the title.  I point this out only because forgetting everything you know from C++ is your first step towards success with Objective-C. ;)

Secondly, your code demonstrates that you don't understand Objective-C or use of the Foundation APIs.

- you aren't allocating instances of NSString anywhere
- you declared an array of 256 NSString instance pointers, probably not what you want
- a properly encoded ASCII string does not include all of the bytes

I would suggest you start [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Comment: That wasn't the question.  I'll try not to react to your condecension.

Comment: His points are valid, the code as you have it now has the problems he listed.

Comment: I apologize if you took it as an insult. It wasn't intended to be.  The code is so far off base that starting from the Objective-C intro documentation is going to be a productive use of time.  And the comment about forgetting C++ is also quite intentional;  I've been teaching Objective-C for 2 decades and the students that had the most difficulty were the ones who made assumptions based on C++ (or some other language's) behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To solve that specific problem, the following code should do the trick:

```
NSMutableArray* ASCIIChars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:256];
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
    {
    [ASCIIChars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", (unsigned char)i]];
    }
```

To be used, later on, as follows:

```
NSString* oneChar = [ASCIIChars objectAtIndex:32]; // for example
```

However, if all you need is an array of characters, you *can* just use a simple C array of characters:

```
unsigned char ASCIIChars [256];
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
    {
    ASCIIChars[i] = (unsigned char)i;
    }
```

To be used, later on, as follows:

```
unsigned char c = ASCIIChars[32];
```

The choice will depend on how you want to use that array of characters.